# syntax error in LogisticRegression

Tags: logistic-regression

I get a syntax error in the following command of LogisticRegression. Can someone please advise where I might be going wrong here?

```
from sklearn import linear_model
lm =  linear_model.LogisticRegression (C = 1e3)
lm.fit (m[:lags].T, np.sign(m[lags])
LogisticRegression (penalty ='l2', tol = .0001, C = 1000000.0, class_weight = None, dual = False, fit_intercept = True, 
intercept_scaling = 1, random_state = None, solver ='liblinear', max_iter = 100, multi_class ='ovr',verbose = 0, 
warm_start = False, n_jobs = 1)
```

Error:

```
File "<ipython-input-33-529ff9190586>", line 4
    LogisticRegression (penalty ='l2', tol = .0001, C = 1000000.0, class_weight = None, dual = False, fit_intercept = True,
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1):

you have missing closing parenthesis here:

```
lm.fit (m[:lags].T, np.sign(m[lags]) <--
```

change to

```
lm.fit (m[:lags].T, np.sign(m[lags]))
```

Comment: Ok Sudhir, this is helpful